# TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found

Tags: python-3.x

```
    if ord(c) >= ord('A') and ord(c) <= ord('z'):
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

Estou a tentar criar um algoritmo de casear cipher, mas tenho um problem com a fundão `ord`, que me diz que estou a fornir uma string de 2 caracteres em vez dum caracter, mas na realidade não é assim. Estou a usar os seguinte loop para iterar através da string `message`:

```
for c in message:
    if ord(c) >= ord('A') and ord(c) <= ord('z'):
```

Eu sei que o erro é nessa instrução, porque se a modifico para:

```
if c >= 'A' and c <= 'z':
```

o programa é executado.

`c` no loop é um caracter, e `A` ou `z` também o são, é por isso que não entendo onde está problema.

Este é o código completo da função:

```
def encrypt(message, i=0): 
    emsg = ""
    for c in message:
        # to be decrypted, the character has to be in the range ["A", "z"]
        if ord(c) >= ord('A') and ord(c) <= ord('z'): #
                # Managing the case between upper and lower cases.
                # Either if 'i' is negative or positive,
                # the current letter is always replaced with
                # a letter which can be found after it,
                # in the ASCII encoding (in my case).
                if ord(c) + i > 90 and ord(c) + i < 97: # [91, 96]
                    dif = (ord(c) + i) - 90 # positions remaining
                    emsg += chr(97 + dif - 1)
                    print("First if")
                elif ord(c) + i > ord('z'): # ]122, - ]
                    dif = (ord(c) + i) - ord('z') # positions remaining
                    emsg += chr(ord('A') + dif - 1) # adds difference starting from 65
                    print("first elif")
                elif ord(c) + i < ord('A'): # [ - , 65[
                    dif = ord('A') - (ord(c) + i) # positions remaining
                    emsg += chr(ord('z') - dif - 1)
                    print("second elif")

                else: # simple case where we just advance the letter
                    emsg += chr(ord(c) + i)
                    print("else")

        else: # It's not a normal char.
            emsg += c
            print("not a normal char.")

    return emsg


print(encrypt(',bc', 1))
```

Comment: nao consigo reproduzir esse erro: In [5]: 

`message = "whatever"

In [6]: for c in message:
   ...:     if ord('A') <= ord(c) <= ord('z'):
   ...:         print("yes")
   ...:`

Comment: Mais uma vez nao deu erro, tanto com python 2.7 como 3. A unica coisa que eu mudei foi a condicao para: `        if ord('A') <= ord(c) <= ord('Z') and ord('a') <= ord(c) <= ord('z'):` ja que as letas nao contiguas na tabela ascii.

Comment: muito estranho mesmo, aqui roda normalmente :(

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17881/discussion-between-lucas-virgili-and-broly).

Comment: Já tentou imprimir `c` e ver o que dá? A propósito, em que sistema operacional você está executando? E qual o *encoding* do seu arquivo fonte? (bastante improvável - em particular no Python 3 - mas pode ser que o que aparenta ser 1 caractere pra você internamente seja 2, por diferença de encodings)

Comment: De fato está difícil reproduzir o problema... No Windows rodou normalmente, e no ideone (que eu presumo ser Linux) [também](https://ideone.com/5kFNdw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive a rever e a modificar ligeiramente a minha função, e agora, *milagrosamente*, ela funciona. Para quem quiser, este é o código completo (se alguém encontrar bugs, que me diga):

```
def encrypt(message, i=0): 
    emsg = ""
    for c in message:
        if (ord('A') <= ord(c) <= ord('Z')) or (ord('a') <= ord(c) <= ord('z')): # [A, Z] U [a, z]
                # Managing the case between upper and lower cases.
                if (ord(c) + i) > 90 and (ord(c) + i) < 97: # [91, 96] of no chars.
                    if i > 0: # i is replaced with a lower case letter (bigger ASCII number)
                        dif = ord(c) + i - 90
                        emsg += chr(97 + dif - 1)
                    elif i < 0: # i is replaced with a upper case letter (smaller ASCII number)
                        dif = 97 - (ord(c) + i)# positions remaining
                        emsg += chr(90 - abs(dif) + 1)
                elif ord(c) + i > ord('z'): # ]122, - ]
                    dif = (ord(c) + i) - ord('z') # positions remaining
                    emsg += chr(ord('A') + dif - 1) # adds difference starting from 65
                elif ord(c) + i < ord('A'): # [ - , 65[
                    dif = ord('A') - (ord(c) + i) # positions remaining
                    emsg += chr(ord('z') - (dif - 1))
                else: # simple case
                    emsg += chr(ord(c) + i)       
        else: # It's not a normal char.
            emsg += c

    return emsg
```